# split multi sheet excel work book to multiple workbooks

Tags: python, python-3.x

While writing the data into new workbook using xlwt, date columns are changed to number columns by default. Need to retain the date format

Tried using datetime function, but i have mix of all columns and among that only one is a date column

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlwt import Workbook
import os

for file in os.listdir('C:\\Users\chidambs\Documents\Shiva\\'):
if file.endswith(".xlsx"):


rb = open_workbook('C:\\Users\chidambs\Documents\Shiva\\'+         str(file),formatting_info=False)
num = rb.nsheets


for a in range(num): 

   rs = rb.sheet_by_index(a)
   sheet = (rs.name)

   new_book = Workbook()
   new_sheet = new_book.add_sheet(sheet)

   for row in range(rs.nrows):
       for col in range(rs.ncols):
           new_sheet.write(row, col, rs.cell(row, col).value)

   new_book.save("C:\\Users\chidambs\Documents\Shiva\\" + str(sheet) + ".xls")
```

Expected :
Week Ending   Col B    Col C .........
3/23/2019
3/23/2019
3/23/2019
3/23/2019
3/23/2019
3/23/2019

Actual :
Week Ending   Col B    Col C ......... 
43547
43547
43547
43547
43547

Comment: Read [Formatting](https://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#formatting)